# why wpf itemlist disconnected after itemsource change

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, user-controls

I am going to make pageable listview.
I almost implemented all features except index display.
I pass listviewitem to converter as multibinding to display the index.
But listview display the index till 2th page, but on 3th page it generate exception beacuse passed listviewitem is disconnected item.

When I use single binding(without startpos), it works well. it generated only when multibinding.

Error screenshot: values[1] is disconnecteditem:

[image: Error screenshot: values[1] is disconnecteditem]

This is usercontrol.xaml.cs file part:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayListProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayList", typeof(List<Retweet>), typeof(PagingGrid));
    public List<Retweet>? DisplayList
    {
        get => (List<Retweet>)this.GetValue(DisplayListProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(DisplayListProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

This is usercontrol.xaml:

```
<ListView Name="list" Grid.Row="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayList}" Background="{StaticResource bBack}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource bBack}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource bBorder}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" >
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="StartPos" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
                                    <!--<Binding Path="DisplayList" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>-->
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>
```

This is converter:

```
public class IndexConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)values[0];
        ListView listView = (ListView)ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);
        int startPos = (int)values[1];
        int index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) + 1 + startPos;
        return index.ToString();
        //return (((List<Retweet>)values[2]).FindIndex(a => a.RetweetId == ((Retweet)values[0]).RetweetId) + (int)values[1]).ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Current usercontrol design:

[image: current usercontrol design]

Comment: Likely a memory leak due to the event handler (not unsubscribed). However, why using the `PropertyChanged` event handler when you already have a full-featured `DependencyProperty` doing the same thing and much more?

Comment: PropertyChanged seems to be that i put before set DependencyProperty, but it is not reason the error, i removed the line, but exception still exist. thanks for your advise, hope to more help.

Comment: Did you really name your custom control class "UserControl"?   That's a bad idea. `UserControl` is a WPF class name already.  I would recommend you change the name of your class to avoid confusion.   I ask because you have a binding to the `StartPos` property of source `AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}`  and the WPF class has no such property.  Give that AncestorType the correct type ane namespace prefix.  e.g. `AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl}`.  I'm not saying this is the cause of your problem but fixing it might make the true issue clearer.

Comment: i already resolved this problem yesterday. thanks for your help.

Comment: @GlobalMan, will you please share the solution? What did you fix to resolve the problem?